# Button text loaded from Storyboard has the wrong color

Tags: ios, swift

I'm running into a very strange issue: I have a trivial view controller which is loaded from a storyboard, and on the initial load, one of the buttons doesn't have the correct text color as specified in IB.

The button is supposed to be blue, but it shows up as white on the initial load.  What's even more strange is, that if I tap the button, or if I load this view a second time from the storyboard, it reverts to the expected color.

Other things I've considered:

- It's not programmatic: there's basically no code in the view controller
- The IB configuration appears to be correct; i.e. the state is "enabled", the button is not marked "hidden" and the alpha is 1.

Is there something I could be missing?

Comment: in simulator or device ?

Comment: what is the button type custom or system ?

Comment: @vivekDas custom